# Остановить setInterval() когда переменная 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Когда пользователю приходит новое сообщение, вывожу в title мигание, что новое сообщение как в вк

```
mounted() {
    this.channelDialogs
      .listen('DialogList',({message,chat_id,id,type,dialog}) => {
              let el = this.dialogs.find((f, idx) => f.id == chat_id);
              if (el){
                  el.message = message;
                  if (chat_id != this.dialogSelect){
                      el.count += 1;
                      this.countNew += 1;
                      if (this.countNew > 0) {
                        const that = this;
                        setInterval(function(){
                            $('title').text(that.countNew + " новых сообщений");
                            $('link[sizes="16x16"]').attr('href','/webassets/favicon/count/' + that.countNew + '.png')
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                document.title = that.title;
                                $('link[sizes="16x16"]').attr('href',that.favicon);
                            }, 1500);
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                  }

              }else{
                  this.dialogs.push(dialog);
              }
      });
}
```

но например если я открываю этот диалог метод selectUser то переменную с количеством сообщений уменьшаю

```
selectUser(id,user,x,avatar, fullname){
  this.dialogIndex  = x;
    let el = this.dialogs.find((f, idx) => idx == x);
    if (el){
        this.countNew -= el.count;
        el.count = 0;
        this.countNewMessages();
    }
},
```

как остановить setInterval(function(){} если переменная `this.countNew = 0`

Comment: очевидно, использовать `clearInterval()`

Comment: `interval = setInterval(...); ...; if (variable == 0) {clearInterval(interval)}`